# Group By with 'HAVING' clause on slick+play

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, slick

Imagine I have a SQL table `grades` which has amongst other fields, the name of the student and the result of the grade:

```
| student  |   grade   |
|----------|:---------:|
| Harry    |    Good   |
| Ron      |    Good   |
| Harry    |  Average  |
| Harry    |    Fail   |
| Hermione | Excellent |
| Hermione | Excellent |
| Ron      |  Average  |
| .....    |    ....   |
```

If I wanted to select all the students with at least two 'Excellent' and zero 'Fail' grades one could do:

```
select student
from grades
group by student
having 
      sum(case when grade = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end) >= 2 and
      sum(case when grade = 'Fail' then 1 else 0 end)
```

How could I translate such a query into Slick?
On the [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/sql-to-slick.html#having) the 'Having' clause they give seems simpler.

```
gradesTables
.groupBy(._student)
.map{ case(student, group) => (student, ???)}
.filter(???)
.list
```

On a related note, why do I get an error with the following:

```
   gradesTables
    .groupBy(._student)
    .map{ case(student, group) => (student, group.filter(_.grade == "Fail").length)}
    .list
```

The error is:

> slick.SlickTreeException: Cannot convert node to SQL Comprehension

Comment: What is your question exactly? `having` is an artifact of an unpleasant grammatical weakness of SQL that is not present in query systems where projection occurs in textual 
order (like it should).

Comment: @AluanHaddad: If `having` is a weakness of SQL, then how do you express it in a superiour *query system*  like slick?

Comment: @dnoeth you just use `filter` or `if` (in a `for` expression) because having is not needed. http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/2.1.0-M2/from-sql-to-slick.html#having

Comment: @AluanHaddad: So you apply both WHERE & HAVING using `filter`, and depending on the previous operation it might filter before or after aggregation?

Comment: It will filter the result of the previous operation. If you aggregate before using `filter` the aggregation will be the input to the filter I would imagine. So if you want to filter the input to `groupBy` then you would need to chain `filter` before `groupBy` because a `filter` chained afterwards would be filtering the groups.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Ok, so how do you translate this `having` to slick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code in Slick will generate the SQL you need:

```
val query: Query[(Rep[String], Rep[Option[Int]], Rep[Option[Int]]), (String, Option[Int], Option[Int]), Seq] =
  grades.groupBy( _.student ).map{ case (student, group) => 
    val groupList = group.map(_.grade)

    val gradeExcel = groupList.map( grade =>
      Case.If(grade === "Excellent").Then(1).Else(0) ).sum
    val gradeFail = groupList.map( grade =>
      Case.If(grade === "Fail").Then(1).Else(0) ).sum

    (student, gradeExcel, gradeFail)
  }.
  filter( g => g._2 >= 2 && g._3 === 0 )

// ...

println("Generated SQL:\n" + query.result.statements)
// Generated SQL:
// List(
//   select "STUDENT", sum((case when ("GRADE" = 'Excellent') then 1 else 0 end)), 
//   sum((case when ("GRADE" = 'Fail') then 1 else 0 end)) from "GRADES" group by "STUDENT" 
//   having (sum((case when ("GRADE" = 'Excellent') then 1 else 0 end)) >= 2) and 
//   (sum((case when ("GRADE" = 'Fail') then 1 else 0 end)) = 0)
// )

db.run(query.result.map(println))
// Vector((Hermione,Some(2),Some(0)))
```